Working with .NET 8, EF (and SQL Server) and concurrency rowversion
I am trying to work with EF and SQL Server. Everything is working nicely, but....
Now I am using rowversion (byte[]) in my entity. I receive on my controller the specific product id, description and rowversion (as we passed along the rowversion from retrieval).
We have found a few different ways to properly use concurrency check, although I am not convinced yet.
This is - for me- the cleanest part (yes, I have left out some pieces for simplicity, e.q. mappers, repositories, validation etc etc):
public async Task<Product> UpdateAsync(string id, byte[] version, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     var product = await context.Products.FirstAsync(e => e.Id == id, cancellationToken);
     product.DescrLg = "nope";
     product.Version = version; //now setting this in my mapper.
     //context.Entry(product).Property(p => p.Version).OriginalValue = version; //this is placed in the interceptor, so EF can correctly do the rowversioning check.

     context.Products.Update(product);
     await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
     return new Product(product.Id, product.DescrLg, product.Version); //this is a different viewModel
}

I have changed the approach to use the interceptor-approach, because in my mappers, I do not want to use the context, just simple mapping.
duplicate mark: Can't Catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException is about not be able to get the concurrency exception, this is not the case. I am able to get the concurrency exception (as desired), the question is if this is the best approach.
We all feel that with EF, EF should be able to determine the rowversion and concurrency without the need of setting the old/original version of the field. I would expect something smarter from EF, or hoping, that setting the rowversion would be enough...
Are there any better alternatives?

this is not working - Please explain in what way it is not working. Compile error? Runtime error? No error but null, empty value or strange value?

The duplicate is the same case. There, AutoMapper does the same as product.Version = version;,

Sorry, do not see it as duplicate, because I can get the concurrency exception working, as intended, but it "feels" wrong, manually setting the original value. In 5 years time I was also hoping that we would have moved away from this, hence the question is changed a bit and asking for advice.

without the need of setting the old/original version of the field. it never required manual change. If you have to set it manually, something is seriously wrong in the application. That field is supposed to be set by the database itself, not the application. In SQL Server the rowversion type is updated automatically. In other databases it should be updated automatically by a trigger. The alternative is for EF to compare all columns for changes.

hoping that we would have moved away from this from what? It sounds like the problem is in the application and table design. Check the SQL Server rowversion type to see how this is supposed to work. For PostgreSQL, the NpgSQL provider uses Xmin for the same reason.

PS: context.Products.Update(product); is an  bug. EF detects changes to the objects it tracks, so it already knows that product.DescrLg was changed and will update only that prooperty. In this case, Update is essentially a no-op. If it's used because AsNoTracking() was also used, that's a serious bug and at best results in updating all columns in all loaded objects instead of just the column that changed.

The question, before revision, was "I was wondering if this is the best way to use it?", where "this" seemed to refer to using rowversion. So, if you want to use concurrency control by setting a previously fetched rowversion, then setting OriginalValue is the best way, because it's the only way. That's what the duplicate points out. The question after revision is very vague, but it should have been asked as a new question. In this form it will be closed as opinion-based though.

That @GertArnold is actually the answer I was looking for.  In 5 years time that is still the correct way using rowversion. IMHO still different than looking WHY something was not working.

Out of curiosity: is there better way then using rowversion for concurrency handling with a stateless BE and FE?

IMO, using rowversion is the best way to implement optimistic concurrency, esp. with EF, because it works out of the box. I don't see how you envision something "smarter". The mechanism always needs something to signal concurrent change. If you want, you can mark other (and multiple) properties as concurrency tokens. It al depends on specific demands.
